# TCPDF: Bumping a barcode one page back?

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

With TCPDF, I have been successful in creating a clean & functional 3 column layout to fit an Avery template for mailing labels, but there is just one issue and below I explain the only issue I'm having.

There are 30 of these labels per sheet, and now I've been able to add USPS Intelligent Mail barcodes as well, (which is a feature built into TCPDF and demonstrated in example 27).

**Here is my issue: the barcode for the last record on each page (record 30) is insisting on inserting itself on the NEXT page.**

[image: Barcode Issue Explanation]

I've highlighted this barcode with yellow to point it out. Barcodes are simply arranged with X & Y coordinates, but it seems the positioning is irrelevant with this last record (30). Any value the Y is set to on record 30 will keep it on the next page-- I even tried putting in a negative value to push it back on to the previous page, but it only disappears if I do this.

How can I place this barcode into its right position?

---

Here is what I have:

Everything BUT the barcode is written together as one field-- (I could not find a way to render the barcodes AND write them together with the address, so X & Y positioning is all I could do).

**Full Address Field:**

- (This is a combination of about 8 different fields rewritten as one).
- Relative to Page
- Height of 1"

PHP Code Before Output:

```
<?php
$this->record++;
$initr=$this->record;
//set top margin
$topmargin=.75; //.75 bumping up the top margin moved the Full Address down and was how I gave the barcode room on the label

// change this number to the number of items per page
$r=($initr % 30);
if ($r==0) {

//also change this to items per page
$r=30;
}

    //column 1
    if (($r % 3) == 1) {
    $x=.25;
    $y=((floor($r/3)+1)*$h)-($h-$topmargin);
}

    //column 2
    if (($r % 3) == 2) {
    $x=3;
    $y=((floor($r/3)+1)*$h)-($h-$topmargin);
}

    //column 3
    if (($r % 3) == 0) {
    $x=5.75;
    $y=((floor($r/3)+1)*$h)-((2*$h)-$topmargin);
}
?>
```

PHP Code After Output:

```
<?php
//change this to number of items per page
if ($r == 30) {
$this->AddPage();
}
?>
```

**Barcode Field:**

- To do the barcode, I added in my "zip code" field because TCPDF would be requiring it after the hyphen in the barcode calculation. Note: I was required to trim out any zip code's hyphens with the "str_replace" function. So I did this for each record in order to position them properly with X & Y.
- Relative to Page
- Height of anything (just to make it show up)
- PHP Code Before Output: http://pastebin.com/AGyY2M1i

I have been working on these barcodes but cannot figure this little issue out.

### Update

This is how these fields were arranged...

[image: TCPDF Order of Fields]

But I just switched them, and now the issue looks easier to resolve.

It seems the only record having problems now is the LAST record. I've searched around a little here with no luck, but is there a way to target the last record?

The reason it is having trouble is because of my "else" statement after all of my "elseif" statements. However, if I take that "else" statement away, turning it into an "elseif" statement like the rest - e.g. elseif ($r == 30) - the 30th barcode on each page disappears (and so does the last record's barcode).

I think I need to be able to target the last record?

Comment: Are you still working on this?  Did you get it working?  btw, in the third pastebin link: the reason the elseif($r==30) thing didn't work is because 30 is outside the range of possible outcomes. In `$r=($initr % 30);` $r will always be 0-29.  Multiples of 30 are fully divisible by 30 and have no remainder after all.  As for targeting the last record, the only way to do that is to know the number of records in the set.  I'd be interested to hear, if you've solved this on your own, what the solution was.

Comment: EPB, Yes, the solution was to rearrange my fields. Sorry, had not updated that here. More details here: http://drupal.org/node/1345182#comment-6993272

Comment: This question may need to close. I have removed a couple of tinyurl.com links, which are now prohibited by the Stack Overflow editor, and they were pointing to a linkedin.com profile that made no sense anyway.